# create and write a txt file in matlab engine

Tags: matlab, writefile, matlab-engine

In Matlab 2010a, I create a new file `data.txt` and write a matrix into the file using the following codes. And this works.

`a=[1,2,3;3,4,5];
 fid=fopen('C:\Users\TOSHIBA\Desktop\data.txt','wt'); 
 fprintf(fid,'%g\n',a);
 fclose(fid);`

However, when I use the same commands in matlab engine as the following statements (written in C language), I can't create a new file `data.txt` or write a matrix into the file.

```
engEvalString(eg,"a=[1,2,3;3,4,5];");
engEvalString(eg,"fid=fopen('C:\Users\TOSHIBA\Desktop\data.txt','wt');");
engEvalString(eg,"fprintf(fid,'%g\n',a);");
engEvalString(eg,"fclose(fid);");
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
csvwrite('C:\Users\TOSHIBA\Desktop\data.txt',a);
```

Comment: I try this command in Matlab and it works. But this command  still doesn't work in matlab engine.